# Looking an inventory software with rack visualisation

Tags: server, hardware

I'm tired of preparing excel list or trello boards and also grafana for tracking my entire datacenter.

I am in need of an inventory software solution that can efficiently track rack information, bare-metal servers, and operating systems all in one place. Despite my extensive search, I have been unable to find a suitable all-in-one software solution.

The product should able to show me racks, and in racks I should be able to place servers, when I click these hosts I should see the description, ips and real-time hardware and usage information. I should also be able to track changes and updates.

Can you give me advice?